# Am I in trouble because of my FLR application?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, visa-change

I was on FLR (FP) or FLR (HRO) visa (one of the two, can't remember, does it matter?) because I was switching from a Tier 4 student visa to a skilled worker visa, but my employer hadn't received its sponsorship license yet.

After the license was received, we switched my visa from FLR to a skilled worker visa and they asked the home office to 'vary the leave'. It was successful and I am currently on a skilled worker visa.

My questions:

1. What is meant by 'varying the leave'?
2. What happened to that FLR
   (HRO/FP) application?
3. If I change jobs in the future, will this be a
   the problem, as I will have to apply for a new skilled worker visa?

Comment: What is FLR? FP? HRO?

Comment: Further leave to remain. I assume you are not aware of this, then you might not know?

Comment: It’s simply a courtesy to explain abbreviations, given that this is not a UK-specific site.

Comment: Nah I wasn't attacking you. Simple questions - would you have any idea about my 3 questions?